# How to show PIL Images as a movie?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I get continuously PIL Images, using `while True` loop, and want to show them as a movie.

I can show an image by `img.show()`, but this code inside the loop makes multiple windows.

Would you tell me the way to display them as a movie?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use ImageMagick in the command line to great a `.gif` file with the following command, assuming your image files are named something like `image-1.png`, `image-2.png`:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
convert -delay 20 -loop 0 image-*.png my_movie.gif
```

This will create a `my_movie.gif` in the same directory where your images are located.

Another way to create a movie from frames is to use Blender, an open source program based on Python. I don't think Pillow supports creating gifs or movie files directly; every solution I have seen involves some other library, so I think the best way is to go with a simple command line tool.